# WPF always on top only for parent

Tags: wpf, windows

I need my window to be always on top but just for his parent.

Is it possible to make a window always on top just for the parent ?

Comment: How did you create the parent-child relation between the windows?

Comment: Not directly related but if you want to launch multiple different form classes  on top of the main parent and maintain the original opening timeline of events then omit the owner property altogether. This way each child window opened by the parent will stay opened on top of the parent. Only hidden when interacting with the parent window but will remain activated but lost focus when interacting with other child windows opened by the parent. Inconsistent use of the owner property results in weird and erratic behavior on child windows.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Set the `Owner` property of your child window, pointing to the opener window. This way it will always be on top of its parent.

```
SomeWindow childWindow = new SomeWindow();
childWindow.Owner = this;
childWindow.Show();
```

Comment: This doesn't always work - I have this set, and the parent window occasionally gets placed above the child window.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old question but the problem of using **Window.Show()** is that if the window lost the focus then the window is placed below. For some applications you need to have a child window an also be able to interact with the other windows. To achieve a effect that the child windows only be hidden when the main window is hidden you need to do:

```
    PopUpWindow PopUp = new PopUpWindow()
    {
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual,
        Left = 0,
        Top = 0,                
        Topmost = true
    };
    PopUp.Show();
```

The **Topmost** property is for showing the window above all, but if we change of application that windows remains on top. So we need to change that property when the mainWindow is **Activated** or **Deactivated**.

```
    public void MainWindow_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PopUp != null)
            PopUp.Topmost = true;
    }
    public void MainWindow_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PopUp != null)
            PopUp.Topmost = false;
    }
```

This approach is done by triggers on the MainWindow and the events on the ViewModel so its a MVVM valid approach, but also you can use events on the code behind.

And in the MainWindow you need to put:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"


<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Activated">
        <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="MainWindow_Activated"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Deactivated">
        <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="MainWindow_Deactivated"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score -1):

By using Owner attribute you can assign its parent so the child element will always be top of its parent

```
window parentWindow = WindowView;
window childWindow = WindowView;
childWindow.Owner = parentWindow;
```